# using db.mycollection.distinct('field1', 'field2') with mongodb / mongoskin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I have the following line in an exports declaration in a user.js file:

```
 db.collection('myList').distinct('field1', 'field2'), function(err, items) {
        res.json(items);
 }
```

The db lookup works fine from the mongo command line. However, when I run the webpage, I get:

```
 TypeError: string is not a function
```

I'm not certain how to proceed at this point. Should I be casting the return to a string somehow before returning it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not seem to be well defined, consider the logic:

```
> db.info.insert({ field1: "this", field2: "that" })
> db.info.insert({ field1: "this", field2: "another" })
> db.info.insert({ field1: "this", field2: "that" })
> db.info.insert({ field1: "this", field2: "another" })
> db.info.distinct('field1', 'field2')
[ "this" ]
```

But what you actually want is:

```
db.info.aggregate([
   {$group: {_id: { field1: "$field1", field2: "$field2" } } }
])
```

Which gives:

```
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "field1" : "this",
                            "field2" : "another"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "field1" : "this",
                            "field2" : "that"
                    }
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The distinct results of the combined fields.

I hope we are learning now.

Comment: Thank you for that, but my question was how do I call myCollection.distinct() from user.js using mongoskin.

Comment: @user1901341 Very well. But you were also told that your usage case will not work. Use [aggregate](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#aggregate) instead. Distinct usage params are [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#distinct).

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason MongoSkin abstraction doesn't provide access to the MongoDB 'distinct' method. To get distinct to work, I had to use the native MongoDB collection and not the abstracted MongoSkin collection. Here is how I did it

```
    var store = mongo.db(connectionString, ackOptions);
    store.open(function(err,resp){
         resp.collection(this.options.collection, {strict: true}, function(err, myCollection) {
            myCollection.distinct('tag',function(err,res){
                console.log(err)
                console.log(res)
            })
        });
    })
```